# MongoDB aggregation - group by date ranges where one document can belong to several ranges

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have next dummy dataset:

```
{"id": 1, "date": "2017-04-01", "total": 1}
{"id": 2, "date": "2017-04-03", "total": 2}
{"id": 3, "date": "2017-04-10", "total": 1}
{"id": 4, "date": "2017-04-11", "total": 1}
```

also I have some fixed value `count_of_days`. Let it equals 5 (`count_of_days = 5`)

I need create next groups:

```
{"2017-04-01 + 5 days": count: 2, sum_of_total: 3}
{"2017-04-03 + 5 days": count: 1, sum_of_total: 2}
{"2017-04-10 + 5 days": count: 2, sum_of_total: 2}
{"2017-04-11 + 5 days": count: 1, sum_of_total: 1}
```

where `count` is count of documents which date field is in range `[date; date + count_of_days]`

so for document with `id=1` we have such group

```
{"2017-04-01 + 5 days": count: 2, sum_of_total: 3}
```

because

doc's 1 `date` is in range `[2017-04-01; 2017-04-06 (+ 5 days)]` and

doc's 2 `date` `2017-04-03` is in range `[2017-04-01; 2017-04-06 (+ 5 days)]`

**How** can I do this using `aggregation framework` or perhaps `Map/Reduce`?

the main goal is productivity and computing speed

Comment: sorry but is is not clear what you are trying to ask, try to refactor your question.

Comment: @leonziyo I've tried, done

Comment: is your date filed a String data type or Date data type?

Comment: @leonziyo actually ISO Date

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to achieve the exact result you asked for, but I was able to group documents based on a fixed time interval instead of an interval relative to the record.

I am assuming your documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b36eb4b4af453e43480473"),
    "id" : 1.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-02T00:21:20.201Z"),
    "total" : 1.0
}
```

Aggregation query:

```
// change this as you need, currently it is the number of milliseconds in 5 days
var interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 5; 

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: { 
            timestamp: { 
                $divide : [
                    { 
                        $subtract: [
                            {
                                $subtract: [ 
                                    '$date', 
                                    new Date("1970-01-01") 
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $mod: [
                                    {
                                        $subtract: [ 
                                            '$date', 
                                            new Date("1970-01-01") 
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    interval
                                ]
                            }
                       ] 
                    }, 
                    interval 
                ] 
            },

            date: 1,

            total: 1,

            id: 1
        }    
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                timestamp: '$timestamp'
            },
            sum_of_total: { $sum: '$total' },
            count: { $sum: 1 }            
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            count: 1,
            sum_of_total: 1,
            rangeStart: { $add: [new Date(0), { $multiply: ['$_id.timestamp', interval] } ] }
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            count: 1,
            sum_of_total: 1,
            rangeStart: 1,
            rangeEnd: { $add: [ "$rangeStart", interval ] }
        }
    }
])
```